# double quote as string in Java

Tags: java, json, string, api

I am writing a solution to make a JSON call using REST assured.. so Trying to create JSON body using excel values dynamically. I am reading all the colum values row by row and writing the values to json object to create JSON body before posting the request. Two of the columns in that excel has no values. when i get the value using column number i am getting 0 as output in console. but in the json call i have to use "" (double quote) no values in those fields. How can i assign just "" as string in java. i tried the below way and its not working for me

```
 loan.setDisbursementDate("\"\"");
```

what i read is this way java should read double quote as string and it should take "" as string and assign the value to the variable. but when i try this jsob body shows the below value "" not just double quotes.
request body i am expecting looks like this

```
"disbursementDate": ""
```

how can i assign just double quote in this case.

thanks

Comment: try loan.setDisbursementDate("\\"\\"")

Comment: @AmitVyas That would be a syntax error, right? The backslashes are escaped, so the second quote ends the string, meaning all the stuff after that isn't supposed to be there

Comment: In java you escape " by \" and the same goes for JSON.You need to escape \ as well...: 
 try loan.setDisbursementDate("\\\"\\\"")

Comment: @AmitVyas ur syntax is giving me syntax error.

Comment: @RahulSingh i tried this and getting below value lumpSumEndDate":"\\\"\\\"

Comment: @sarath: Does this :loan.setDisbursementDate( '""'") work? {Double quotes inside single quotes} .This is how empty strings can be represented in json

Comment: If you are working with a json serialization library, no need to do anything, just use an empty string, pretty straight forward.

Comment: Java will correctly interpret `"\"\""` (what you have) as string consisting of exactly two quotes. So if it doesnt work, that means its not Javas fault but how your method interprets the data. Since you did not share anything beyond that, its impossible to answer your question in the current state, hence voting to close.

Comment: @Enterman probably is on the right track here. You are using a _library_ to write the JSON. You want the value of a field to be an empty string. So, just give the library an empty string, and let the library do its job. Don't try to tell the library what an empty string is supposed to look like in the JSON file. In fact, don't try to tell the library what _anything_ is supposed to look like in the file. Just give the library the names and the values, and let it do its job.

Comment: this is how my setter looks like
@JsonProperty("disbursementDate")
public String getDisbursementDate() {
return disbursementDate;
}

Comment: @SolomonSlow ok let me try that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow your solution worked, i just left it as empty string and library took care of the rest. thanks